# Dart equality for different types

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I want to implement class-like enum

```dart
@immutable
abstract class Enum<T> {
  final T? value;
  
  @literal
  const Enum([this.value]);

  List<Object?> get values => value != null ? [value] : const [];

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object? other) {
    if (other is T) {
      return value == other;
    }
    return other is Enum && other.value == value;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => super.hashCode;
}

class EnumClass extends Enum<int> {
  @literal
  const EnumClass(int value) : super(value);

  static const zero = const EnumClass(0);
  static const one = const EnumClass(1);

  // You can have any functions you want
}
```

so that I can do the following operations

```dart
if(EnumClass.zero == 0) {
  // This works!
}
```

but my test failed

```dart
void main() {
  test('Compare EnumClass.zero with 0', () {
    if (EnumClass.zero == 0) {
      print('same'); // This is printed
    }
    expect(EnumClass.zero, 0); // But the test failed
  });
}
```

The comparison with 0 works as expected but the expect function doesn't work.
What should I do to make the test pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

```dart
expect(EnumClass.zero, 0);
```

fails, but:

```dart
expect(0, EnumClass.zero);
```

succeeds. `expect(actual, expected)` by default uses an `equals` `Matcher`, and the implementation for `equals` [checks `expected == actual` instead of `actual == expected`](https://github.com/dart-lang/matcher/blob/1f7b6f0cb15eb6659a1de0513571575a5c8a51d0/lib/src/equals_matcher.dart#L183).

Arguably it'd be more intuitive if `expect(A, B)` matched the original order by comparing `A == B` instead of `B == A`, but having non-symmetric equality is going to be error-prone and probably is not a good idea anyway.

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/matcher/issues/94.

Comment: And since == is generally supposed to be symmetric, I wonder how to fix that.

Comment: Since Dart doesn't support overloading, you can't really make `operator ==` symmetric if one of the types involves a class you don't control. You could make some `bool equals(Object object1, Object object2) => (object1 == object2 || object2 == object1);` function if you really wanted, but it's still probably not a good idea since asymmetry also might mean that the `hashCode` values would be different.